# range filter not working in django

Tags: python, django

I want to filter my queryset on the basis of two values.

I want result between two numbers.I am trying some code but it is not working .It did not return me proper result.
my code

```
def project(request):
    try:

        proTitle = request.GET.get('title')
        ProDescription = request.GET.get('description')
        funAria = request.GET.get('funAria')
        femaleReq = request.GET.get('femaleReq')
        cost_gte = int(request.GET.get('cost_gte'))
        cost_lte = int(request.GET.get('cost_lte'))
    except:
        pass


    if cost_gte and cost_lte :
        list4 = []

        result = Project.objects.filter(budgeted_cost__gte=cost_gte , budgeted_cost__lte=cost_lte )
        print result
        for res in result:

            list4.append(res.project_id)
        data ={'cost result':list4}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))




return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Some time it returns all product and some time it return none.I cant understand why it is not working.

i also try by range

```
result = Product.objects.filter(cost__range=(cost_gte,cost_lte))
```

but is also behave same.Please guide me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe `cost__rage` → `cost__range`?

Comment: If the values youre passing to `filter` are different, the result would obviously not be the same. Trying testing with fixed values (*not those from `request.GET`*) and see what happens

Comment: Apart from indentation and typos, there's not much wrong here. We'd need to see the model, your actual data, the actual values used. But in particular this doesn't seem to be your real code (the typos and indentation will have happened when you typed the code in here) so there may be another problem that we can't see because you didn't copy and paste.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich i have added my code.

Comment: @Moses Koledoye i have tried with fiexd values.but did return me proper result

Comment: data is not defined in the last return

Comment: There is no typo error and no indentation error but still my code is not working

Comment: @S.deMelo i am not getting your point

Comment: What kind of values are you using? Because of that `if` statement, if either cost_lte or cost_gte is 0, it skips it all.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich i am getting both values.both cost_lte and cost_gte has values.I am using int values for both

Comment: Have you tried in the Django shell with fixed values?  Like:
`results = Project.objects.filter(budgeted_cost__gte=5, budgeted_cost__lte=50000)`

Comment: @vikrant Just that the last line will give you an UnboundLocalError if either cost_gte or cost_lte is 0, because data is not defined in that case.

Comment: How is the field in the model defined? What is your actual data? We don't have enough info in this question, the problem isn't in your view (apart from that if statement).

Comment: Thanks...RemcoGerlich ...i defined cost field in database as char field. so  this problem occured.Not i am define it as integerfield.Now it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

In python when you use `range` it means `range1 <= i < range2`, but the filter you are looking for your query is `range1 <= i <= range2`, so you should not look forward  `range` instead go

```
 result = Project.objects.filter(budgeted_cost__gte=cost_gte , 
budgeted_cost__lte=cost_lte )
```

to get desired output.